# Error mounting drives

Tags: linux-mint, boot, mount, fstab, automounting

I am not able to mount the disk. It is showing error.

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda3: Command-line `mount "/media/tusharmakkar08/Local"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: [mntent]: line 1 in /etc/fstab is bad
mount: can't find /media/tusharmakkar08/Local in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

Output of

```
 sudo blkid
```

is

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="FA38015738011473" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Local Disk" UUID="01CD72098BB21B70" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="2ca94bc3-eb3e-41cf-ad06-293cf89791f2" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="CFB1-5DDA" TYPE="vfat"
```

Output of

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

is :

```
UUID=01CD72098BB21B70 /media/tusharmakkar08/Local Disk1 ntfs-3g nosuid,nodev 0 0
UUID=FA38015738011473 /media/sda2 ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
UUID=2ca94bc3-eb3e-41cf-ad06-293cf89791f2 / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=CFB1-5DDA /media/tusharmakkar08/CFB1-5DDA vfat defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use \x20 for space.

That is hex value for ASCII (and utf-8 encoded) space.

Or you can use the octal variant `\040`.

So that would be (in fstab):

```
UUID=01CD72098BB21B70 /media/tusharmakkar08/Local\x20Disk1
# or
UUID=01CD72098BB21B70 /media/tusharmakkar08/Local\040Disk1
```

If you are not to familiar with ASCII fun install `ascii` and:

```
ascii     # decimal and hex view
ascii -o  # octal view
```

Non the less I'd also recommend, like [@TNW](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/37072/tnw), changing the mount point to one without space. Generally makes things easier. You can also change the label
though that might affect other things if you have something configured to recognize it as it is.

Comment: Related: `LABEL="PHONE\0x20CARD" /mnt/phone_card vfat defaults,user 0 0` did not work while `LABEL="PHONE\040CARD" /mnt/phone_card vfat defaults,user 0 0` worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have a whitespace in your first mount point name. Best thing you can do is to rename it so it doesn't have whitespaces and change your /etc/fstab accordingly.