# How to edit fstab to mount bind a directory that have spaces in the PATH at start in wsl2

Tags: mount, fstab, bind-mount

I am currently using wsl2 on windows and I use MS OneDrive locally in parallel for my studies.
Actually I sync each file with my OneDrive account.
AS my Onedrive folder's name is like :

> Onedrive - SchoolName

And that for my courses I need to use WSL2 and I want to acceed to my windows file without the spaces in the path.
The solution I found is to use mount bind command :

> sudo mount --bind /mnt/c/Users/MyName/OneDrive\ -\ SchoolName/Project ~/Project/

This is actually working but I want to edit my fstab to not type the command each time I start my WSL. And I do not know how to do because each tuto I found wasn't working.

Thank you for your tips !

Comment: You can use octal (\040) or hex (\x20) escape values for the space character - see [Error mounting drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72729/error-mounting-drives)

Answer (score 0):

`fstab(5)` documents that `\040` can be used to substitute a space… but only in the second field; you have it in the first field.

A quick workaround is to make a symlink to the source directory somewhere, then bind-mount that:

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Users/MyName/OneDrive\ -\ SchoolName/Project /.onedrive-link
```

Then you can bind-mount `/.onedrive-link` to `~/Project/`.

---

At this point, the obvious question is, do you still need the bind mount? You can just do:

```
sudo rmdir ~/Project
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/MyName/OneDrive\ -\ SchoolName/Project ~/Project
```

You’ll end up with a symlink that’s even owned by your regular user and doesn’t need superuser privilegues to be modified.

Comment: `\040` in first field works for me

Answer (score 0):

there's an easy solution for this, just do an ls command and tab until you get to your folder.

for example:

ls /volume1/test/etc(tab after every / so putty or whatever you use completes the name of the folder and it will automatically add the spaces symbols you need).

Once you reach the folder you want to mount just replace the "ls" with "mount --bind"  and of course add the destination after the first path.

This will avoid headaches!

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

what I did on my fedora 35 was open disks and edit their mount options. unfortunately, wsl doesn't provide GUI so I'll do my best to give you an example based on my own fstab

```
/mnt/c/Users/MyName/OneDrive / ntfs-3g defaults,bind 0 0
```

the `bind` option should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I have a gui using a server X. Is there a gui solution ?

Comment: install disks, go to your partition, right-click and choose edit mount options, disable User Session Defaults, check mount at system startup, check show in user interface, add defaults,bind to options which should be the one above Mount Point and edit Mount Point as well to get the results you need

Comment: Actually I have this error when trying to acceed gnome-disks
(gnome-disks:60): GNOME-Disks-ERROR **: 10:05:36.329: Error getting udisks client: Could not connect: No such file or directory
Trace/breakpoint trap
Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

if you can't use disks, you have use terminal file editor `nano`

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
#at the end of document
/source /destination none defaults,bind 0 0
```

I myself don't use defaults option I recommend these:

```
/mnt/c/Users/MyName/OneDrive /home/(your username)/Project nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,bind 0 0
```

if it worked make sure to tell us.

EDIT 1:

I know it's been a long time but I think The Situation does not need an interference anymore.
right now I'm an windows 11 insider (Build 25115) and with Hyper-V active and Hypervisor Disabled.
I can see my Ubuntu WSL on explorer and if I have permissions I can write to it.
and the drives are automatically mounted.
this is my fstab (almost empty):

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 1
```

and this is my /mnt (using ls command from Ubuntu WSL):

```
mohsentux@LovelyBloom:/mnt$ ls
c  d  e  f  wsl  wslg
```

so the situation has officially resolved itself so to speak.

Comment: Actually it is not working, I have search for solutions but I think it is a particular behavior of Ubuntu in WSL2

Comment: Can you explain the line you recommended ? Thank you.